# Word or Phrase for Indirect Verbal Deception

Tags: phrase-requests

Is there an English word or phrase which describes conversations intended to be overheard by others, which primarily contains misinformation meant to be believed by those who overhear?

Example:

During an office conversation between Tim and Carlos, Tim says out loud, "Jeff will go to Singapore after leaving Hong Kong".

- It's subsequently discovered that Tim knew Jeff was not going to Singapore
- Assume that Tim merely wanted those who overheard to think Jeff was going to Singapore

"Deception" is possible, but seems too generic.  I'm more interested in specifically describing the indirect nature of the event (i.e. Tim does not say this directly to those he wants to deceive).

Comment: 'Dissimulation' is not really that different in meaning from 'deception', but is more unusual and so might connote deviousness better.

Answer (score 2):

[Disinformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disinformation)

" intentionally false or inaccurate information that is spread deliberately. It is an act of deception and false statements to convince someone of untruth"

Comment: +1 And *disinformation* is often propogated in a channel that appears to be private or secret, to further enhance its apparent truth.

Answer (score 1):

I think [mislead](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Mislead) can fit the context described:

> - To lead into error of thought or action, especially by intentionally deceiving.

Or [misinform:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/misinform)

> - to give false or misleading information to.

Source: TFD